# IR2110 not working correctly in LTspice: Length shorter than recommended

Tags: ltspice, gate-driving

I want to use an [IR2110](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e) gate driver in LTspice. I downloaded the model from the Infineon website and implemented the symbol in my LTspice circuit:

[image]

I only want to use and test low-side switching, so VB and HO are floating, and VS and HIN are tied to ground.

However, when simulating for 100 ms, the simulation stops at around 60 ms. The Spice error log shows me the following problems:

> C2: Increased Cpar to 2.2e-011
> Instance "m:u1:_gd_template:_lo_stage:_lo_nmos": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
> Instance "m:u1:_gd_template:_lo_stage:_lo_pmos": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
> Instance "m:u1:_gd_template:_ho_stage:_ho_nmos": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
> Instance "m:u1:_gd_template:_ho_stage:_ho_pmos": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
> Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded.
> Heightened Def Con from 0.00200011 to 0.00200011
> Heightened Def Con from 0.00300008 to 0.00300008
> Heightened Def Con from 0.00400011 to 0.00400011
> Heightened Def Con from 0.00500008 to 0.00500008
> Heightened Def Con from 0.00600011 to 0.00600011

I don't understand what the "length shorter than recommended for level 1 MOSFET" problem is. What is the cause? I didn't modify Infineon's Lib. I also tried an IR2113 but had the same results.

Comment: Did you try to bias the VB and VS pin with a floating 12-V supply and have the HO pin loaded by a 10-k resistor connected to this floating source GND?

Comment: The MOSFET message you are getting is more of a warning saying that it's not recommended to use a LEVEL=1 MOSFET model with a length of `1u`.  I don't think it's a good idea to start modifying Infineon's subcircuit, because it's likely they knew what they were doing.  Regardless, I think those warnings are unrelated to the actual problem you are having.  Try the above suggestion.